# Paginate comments to Posts

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pagination

I have a comment form for my posts. It looks like this

view.py

```py
def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.author = request.user
            #comment.author.photo = object.author.profile.image.url
            comment.save()
            return redirect('Post-detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name='内容')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('text',)
        widgets = { #size of textbox
          'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':4}),
        }
```

Where should I add pagination function to my comments to make it works?
I have a pagination for my posts, but posts are using a `DetailView` class and I dont know how to make it work for comment `function`

Comment: Do you want to load all comments and then paginate the full set of returned results? Or do you want to make dynamic loading to fetch the next *n* number of comments on scroll, click, etc?

Comment: #JacobIRR I would like to load it all and make n number of pages with next button to show 5 comments on page, but it will becomes something like load next page in page, wouldn't it?  So probably dynamic one will become easier

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to do that in `Post-detail` view. As `DetailView` does not provide pagination, so you need to provide them on your own. You can override the get context method. For example:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        _list = Comment.objects.filter(post=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        paginator = Paginator(_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        context['comments'] = paginator.get_page(page)
        return context
```

And render comments in Template like this:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if comments.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ comments.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ comments.number }} of {{ comments.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if contacts.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ comments.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ comments.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

More information can be found in [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view) as well.

Comment: thanks, but it show this:"ImproperlyConfigured at /post/31/

PostDetailView is missing a QuerySet. Define PostDetailView.model, PostDetailView.queryset, or override PostDetailView.get_queryset()."

Comment: @MarcelKopera as per your question, you are using a detail view to render post, right? I am just showing an example view where I have overridden `get_queryset()` method

Comment: Sorry, I overridden get_coxt_data method

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be done.

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

# Create a custom pagination class.
class CommentPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 1000
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 10000
```

```
# Define the Pagination class in PostDetailView.
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
     pagination_class = CommentPagination
```

```
# This is how api can be called.
# something.com/comment/?page=4
```